# Eclipse rcp disable exit button in an eclipse application

Tags: button, eclipse-rcp, default, exit

how can I disable the window top-right button to close application?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can disable it (like make it gray) since it is managed by the underlying OS window manager, not by SWT directly.

You can add a listener though, in order to ignore any close event, a bit like in [this snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet99.java?view=markup&content-type=text%2Fvnd.viewcvs-markup&revision=HEAD):

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Snippet99 {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.addListener (SWT.Close, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            int style = SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;
            MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox (shell, style);
            messageBox.setText ("Information");
            messageBox.setMessage ("Close the shell?");
            event.doit = messageBox.open () == SWT.YES;
        }
    });
    shell.pack ();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

In your case, simply set '`event.doit`' to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to "iconify" the application if the user wants to close the application, that means the application is moved into the tray-item. Add the following to your ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor:

a. Override postWindowOpen

```
public void postWindowOpen() {
   Shell shell = getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell();
   boolean trayEnabled = false;
   trayEnabled = enableTray();
}
```

b. Implement tray support

```
    /* Enable System-Tray Support */
    private boolean enableTray() {
        /* Avoid that this is being called redundantly */
        if (this.fTrayEnabled) {
            return true;
        }
        /* Only enable for Primary Window */
        IWorkbenchWindow primaryWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()[0];
        if (primaryWindow == null || !primaryWindow.equals(getWindowConfigurer().getWindow())) {
            return false;
        }

        final Shell shell = primaryWindow.getShell();
        final Tray tray = shell.getDisplay().getSystemTray();

        /* Tray not support on the OS */
        if (tray == null) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Create Item in Tray */
        this.fTrayItem = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
        this.fTrayItem.setToolTipText(Platform.getProduct().getName());
        this.fTrayEnabled = true;

        this.fTrayItem.setVisible(false);
        /* Apply Image */
        this.fTrayItem.setImage(trayIcon);
        /* Minimize to Tray on Shell Iconify if set */
        this.fTrayShellListener = new ShellAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void shellIconified(final ShellEvent e) {
                if (!ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.this.fBlockIconifyEvent && ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.this.fMinimizeFromClose) {
                    moveToTray(shell);
                }
            }
        };
        shell.addShellListener(this.fTrayShellListener);

        /* Show Menu on Selection */
        this.fTrayItem.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {


            public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
                MenuManager trayMenu = new MenuManager();

                /* Restore */
                trayMenu.add(new ContributionItem() {
                    @Override
                    public void fill(final Menu menu, final int index) {
                        MenuItem restoreItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
                        restoreItem.setText("Restore from Tray");
                        restoreItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                                restoreFromTray(shell);
                            }
                        });
                        menu.setDefaultItem(restoreItem);
                    }
                });

                /* Separator */
                trayMenu.add(new Separator());

                /* Other Items */
                ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.this.fActionBarAdvisor.fillTrayItem(trayMenu);

                Menu menu = trayMenu.createContextMenu(shell);
                menu.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        /* Handle DefaultSelection */
        this.fTrayItem.addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
                /* Restore from Tray */
                if (!shell.isVisible()) {
                    restoreFromTray(shell);
                } else {
                    moveToTray(shell);
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    /* Move to System Tray */
    private void moveToTray(final Shell shell) {
        this.fTrayItem.setVisible(true);
        this.fBlockIconifyEvent = true;
        try {
            shell.setVisible(false);
        } finally {
            this.fBlockIconifyEvent = false;
        }

        this.fMinimizedToTray = true;
    /**
     * @param shell
     */
    public void restoreFromTray(final Shell shell) {

        /* Restore Shell */
        shell.setVisible(true);
        shell.setActive();
        shell.layout(true);

        /* Un-Minimize if minimized */
        if (shell.getMinimized()) {
            shell.setMinimized(false);
        }
        this.fTrayItem.setVisible(false);

        if (this.fTrayTeasing) {
            this.fTrayItem.setImage(this.trayImage);
        }

        this.fTrayTeasing = false;
        this.fMinimizedToTray = false;
    }

    /* Disable System-Tray Support */
    private void disableTray() {

        /* Avoid that this is being called redundantly */
        if (!this.fTrayEnabled) {
            return;
        }

        /* First make sure to have the Window restored */
        restoreFromTray(getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell());

        this.fTrayEnabled = false;
        this.fMinimizedToTray = false;

        if (this.fTrayItem != null) {
            this.fTrayItem.dispose();
        }

        if (this.fTrayShellListener != null) {
            getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().removeShellListener(this.fTrayShellListener);
        }
    }
```

c. Override preWindowShellClose

```
@Override
public boolean preWindowShellClose() {
    final res =  true ;
    this.fMinimizeFromClose = true;
    getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().notifyListeners(SWT.Iconify, new Event());
    res = false;
    this.fMinimizeFromClose = false;
    return res;
}
```

HTH
Tom

Comment: Interesting alternative (didn't see it right away at the time). +1

Comment: This got me there in the end, but it took a lot of work. You don't show the declaration of your class variables (like fBlockIconifyEvent, fMinimizeFromClose, etc) and some of them aren't necessary. Also there is no fillTrayItem by default on ApplicationActionBarAdvisor. Still, with these flaws, it gave me the comprehensive solution I needed.